# How to convert to camel casing after a symbol?

Tags: c#

```
Input #2: profile.Address.AddressLine1
Result: profile.address.addressLine1

Input #2: MyName
Result: myName
```

---

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputText = "profile.Business.AddressLine1"; //profile.business.addressLine1
            //string inputText = "MyName"; //myName
            string result = null;

            if (inputText.Contains('.'))
            {
                //make first character lowercase
                result = inputText.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + inputText.Substring(1);

                //Loop to find period symbol
                //make the next character after the period symbol lowercase
            }
            else
            {
                //make first character lowercase
                result = inputText.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + inputText.Substring(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: What should return for `portfellimit1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions*:

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq; // For test only 
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  Func<string, string> toCamel = (source) =>
    Regex.Replace(source, @"\b\p{Lu}", m => m.Value.ToLower());

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    @"profile.Business.AddressLine1",
    @"MyFunction(Value, SomeId);",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-40} => {toCamel(test)}"));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

we `Replace` every *uppercase letter* (`\p{Lu}`) which is preceeded by word boundary (`\b`) with lowercase one

**Outcome:**

```
profile.Business.AddressLine1            => profile.business.addressLine1
MyFunction(Value, SomeId);               => myFunction(value, someId);
```

If you want to convert after `.` only, just change the pattern into

```
@"\.\p{Lu}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
var input = "profile.Business.AddressLine1";
var result = string.Join(".",
         input.Split('.')
         .Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) 
               ? "" : Char.ToLower(x.First()) + x.Substring(1)));
```

---

Steps to solve your issue:

1. Split your `input` string using `.`.
2. Change your first letter of each word to lower and concatenate rest of the string.
3. Again join array with `.`

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xFCDPe)

Inputs:

```
var input = "profile.Business.AddressLine1";
var test = "Test..Test";
```

Output:

```
profile.business.addressLine1
test..test
```

Comment: Caveat: This might throw an exception for inputs that have two consecutive dots for some reason.

Comment: This does not compile - please check yourself

Comment: The added Where will do more than camelCase after dots: Test..Test => test.test but expected is test..test

Comment: @SirRufo, thanks for your input, it was really valuable corner cases. I updated my answer to support your both comments Kindly check. I used ternary operator instead of where clause to avoid empty string issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputText = "profile.Business.AddressLine1"; 
        convertToCamelCase(inputText); //profile.business.addressLine1
    }


    static string convertToCamelCase(string inputText)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        if (inputText.Contains('.'))
        {
            var inputs = inputText.Split('.');

            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
            {
                inputs[i] = inputs[i].Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + inputs[i].Substring(1);
            }

            result = string.Join(".", inputs);
        }
        else
        {
            result = convertToCamelCase(inputText);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
static string convertToCamelCase(string inputText)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText)) return result;

    var inputs = inputText.Split('.');
    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputs[i])) continue;
        inputs[i] = inputs[i].Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + inputs[i].Substring(1);
    }

    result = string.Join(".", inputs);
    return result;
}
```